# How can I make my linksys router always have the same internal IP

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I have a modem which is always:

```
192.168.1.1
```

My computer is `102.168.1.5`, my wife's phone is `192.168.1.4` etc. I reserved these through mac addresses on my Linksys' LAN admin page.

How can I make sure that the router itself will always have the same internal IP of 192.168.1.2? I want to use readyshare to stream movies but I can't until I can force it to be on the same IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal address of router is set to a static IP address so you don't need to worry about it changing. This is typically done on the LAN settings configuration page.

Note: it may be possible to allow for dynamic addressing, however, I have never seen a router that has this option.